# UIImageView and Window Orientation Problem

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiimageview, orientation, nswindow

**WHAT I WANT TO DO**

What I want is an imageview on top of the application, which I can control it's appearance. For example, in the homepage I don't want the banner, but in another view I do. That means that if I do want to have the banner, I have to shift down the whole view.

**WHAT I'VE DONE**

The following is within my App Delegate. Basically, I am shifting the view of the customTabBarController down 145 px for the banner.

```
if ([self.customTabBarController interfaceOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {

[customTabBarController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 145, 768,1024-145)];
banner = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 145)];

}
else if ([self.customTabBarController interfaceOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {

    [customTabBarController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 768,1024-145)];
    banner = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 768+145, 768, 145)];

}

banner.image = image;

banner.hidden = NO;

[self.window addSubview:banner];
```

**WHAT THE PROBLEM IS**

Now, I've done the portrait orientation part, but when I try to change orientations, the image changes orientation along too; meaning the image turns sideways when I change the iPad to landscape and upside down. Basically, it stays at one side of the iPad at all times.

Can anyone please help? Suggestions on other methods are welcome too.

EDIT: I realize I didn't implement the setFrame for landscape orientation, but I wanted to finish implementing it for upside down portrait orientation first, but the code does not work. What the application looks like when it's upside down is the banner is on the bottom and the image is upside down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See "[Orientation Problem while using insertSubview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585845/orientation-problem-while-using-insertsubview/5585924#5585924)." You should generally not insert views into the `UIWindow` itself. It does not rotate. You should insert them into the `window.rootViewController.view` or below so that you will get the right transform automatically. Otherwise, you will need to calculate the effective transform yourself using a method like `effectiveTransform` given in "[wrong orientation on UIViewController while animating it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234182/wrong-orientation-on-uiviewcontroller-while-animating-it/5234649#5234649)." Whenever possible, though, use the root view. It does all the magic for you.

Comment: Well the problem is, I want to be able to put this UIImageView on top of a UISplitViewController. As you probably know, I can't set the frame of the UISplitViewController. That's why I resorted to putting it in the NSWindow, but now I have to deal with all the orientation problems.. Any suggestions?

Comment: As noted, insert them into `window.rootViewController.view`. It's usually a `UILayoutContainerView`, which is a private class that's responsible for things like being correctly rotated. You usually can also adjust its frame if you want to move the whole interface around.

Comment: I feel like I may be missing something here, though. Is your only concern the rotation of the image, or are you also having trouble getting your box in the right place?

Comment: Setting the frame of the other view I'll be fine with for now, what I'm having trouble is getting the image to appear within     window.rootViewController.view; I tried window.rootViewController.view addSubview:imageView, but that didn't seem to work. Am I supposed to create a UIViewController and connect them in the xib file?

Comment: No, but make sure that window.rootViewController is wired to something (make sure it's not nil). If you created your project with a template, it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about putting all that into a UIViewController which supports multiple orientations? You might use an autoresizing mask to achieve the correct size in the different orientations.

Answer (score 0):

You can register for orientation change notifications and apply a CGTransform to your banner UIView